# Remove Website from Gmail Spam Filter

Tags: email, gmail, spam

How do I make sure that emails from my website doesn't show up in Gmail's spam filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these emails from your website appearing in your inbox? or emails from your site appearing in other people's inboxes?

If its the first, add the the email addresses to your contacts list.

If its the second, ask people to add the email addresses to their contacts. Alternately, you can send messages that are good quality, not annoying, and not spam.

Also, read this thread [How to stop Gmail from marking mails sent by my web app as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370620/how-to-stop-gmail-from-marking-mails-sent-by-my-web-app-as-spam)