# Mails sent through gmail using java mail api are delivered to spam. How to make them delivered to the inbox?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, spam, inbox

We've an application which is hosted on Amazon EC2. It is connecting to the gmail servers for sending the email to the registered users using Java Mail API. It sends emails using the gmail servers using the email address support@domainname.com(not gmail.com email address). However, recently, the emails are getting delivered to the Spam folder of the users. Can you please suggest me how to over come this problem and have the mail delivered to the inbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Gmail from marking mails sent by my web app as spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370620/how-to-stop-gmail-from-marking-mails-sent-by-my-web-app-as-spam)

Comment: [So you'd like to send some email through code?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple if reasons why your emails are being delivered to the "Spam folder":

1. You haven't added SPF domain records. The SPF records are used to set from which IP addresses you will be sending emails. Every other IP address will be considered as spam. ( http://www.openspf.org/ )
2. You are sending too much emails per hour - if you are sending many emails per hour you may get added in a blacklist. These blacklists are checked by the most popular email service providers such as gmail, hotmail and so on.
3. Your IP address was blacklisted ( http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx/ )

Comment: The cms editing software which was used to update the template was inserting some weird characters, which lead gmail to consider that this is a spam mail. After fixing this, the mails are getting delivered to the inbox.